# Why won't console window remain hidden while using Task Scheduler hidden property?

Tags: windows, desktop, console, windows-task-scheduler, background

I'm trying to get my console program to run without being visible on the desktop. In Task Scheduler in Windows 11, I tried enabling it as a service and ticking the hidden checkbox, but it doesn't do anything when I use the log in trigger for Task Scheduler. The console window stays visible.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to change the beginning of the command.
Like in stead of "blabla.exe"  --> "cmd /c blabla.exe"
or "explorer blabla.exe"
These are tricks/workarounds that are sometimes helpfull.

Another way to go around it is to use powershell.exe to start the exefile in a hidden window.
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle hidden

Good luck :)